# Angular 6 - call function on click OR focus

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to be able to call a function from a component only on click OR focus. Here is a part of the components HTML:

```
<div class="form-add-new__input-box">
     <input
           #commentCategories
           class="form-add-new__category-box"
           (click)="toggleCategoriesSelection($event)"
           (focus)="toggleCategoriesSelection($event)"
           (keyup)="searchCategory($event.target.value)"
           tabindex="0"
           placeholder="Search or select">
     <span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
</div>
```

and the function:

```
public toggleCategoriesSelection(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.categoriesSelectOpen = !this.categoriesSelectOpen;
}
```

Basically I want to call toggleCategoriesSelection on click OR focus - right it is called 2 times on first click. I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
(click | focus)="toggleCategoriesSelection($event)"
```

But unfortunately, it doesn;t work like this. How can I do this?

Comment: If I want to click it, don't I always have to focus it anyway because I'm moving my cursor onto it? To only call it once in your first solution, try placing some debounce or throttle functionality before executing the actual code.

Comment: Just write (focus)="toggleCategoriesSelection($event)" . Focus and click are same.

Comment: This is a toggle, clicking it again when focused doesn't toggle selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you may not need to call **toggleCategoriesSelection** on both the **click** and **focus** events. But if you want to do so you can use something like below.

Here we are debouching frequent function calls occurring during the **smallTimeout**.

```
timeOutExceeded = true // initial value

public toggleCategoriesSelection(event: Event): void {
    if (this.timeOutExceeded) {
        // your logic
        this.timeOutExceeded = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.timeOutExceeded = true;    
        }, smallTimeout);
    }
}
```

Also you may look into **RXJS debouncing** (or any other such techniques) below.

https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613

Comment: Works like a charm :) I've also added a (blur) for the same function and it is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Add stop propagation method to your click and focus event.

```
 <input
           #commentCategories
           class="form-add-new__category-box"
           (click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();toggleCategoriesSelection($event)"
           (focus)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();toggleCategoriesSelection($event)"
           (keyup)="searchCategory($event.target.value)"
           tabindex="0"
           placeholder="Search or select">
     <span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
```

hope i help you!

Comment: Edited: you can try now with prevent default too.